# Ansibleを使い、pyenvからPythonをインストールしpipモジュールを使う方法

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible

VagrantからAnsibleスクリプトを呼び出し、
pyenvを利用してPythonを構築しし、最終的にDjangoをインストールするスクリプトを実現したいのですが、
下記のスクリプトを使用したところ

```
- name: 指定バージョンのPythonをインストールする
  shell: bash -lc "pyenv install {{ python_version }}"
  become: false

- name: 作業用ディレクトリに指定バージョンを反映する
  shell: bash -lc "pyenv local {{ python_version }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ work_dir }}"
  become: false

- name: pipアップグレード
  shell: bash -lc "pip install --upgrade pip"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ work_dir }}"
  become: false

- name: install django
  pip:
    name: django
    chdir: "{{ work_dir }}"
    version: "{{ django_version }}"
    executable: pip
  become: false
```

下記のエラーが出ました。pipモジュールがないとのことだったのですが、
vagrant ssh でゲストOSにログインするとpipコマンドは無事見つかりました。
pyenvからpythonを構築し、その影響下にあるpipをAnsibleから呼び出すことは可能でしょうか。
ご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
TASK [django : install django] *************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find any of pip to use.  pip needs to be installed."}
    to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/playbooks/main.retry
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
AnsibleはデフォルトのPython(/usr/bin/python)を使用しているため、
下記のようなモジュールを使い、Pythonインタプリタを変更する必要があります。

```
set_fact: ansible_python_interpreter=/home/{{ work_user }}/.pyenv/shims/python
```